# Proving that a generic linear operator is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, operator-theory

**Context.**

I am attending a *Functional Analysis* class and we're currently going over normed spaces. In one of the classes, my teacher proved the boundedness of the operator below using a really strong auxiliary lemma that I will link in the next paragraph. After doing so, we proved equivalence of norms in any finite-dimensional normed space and many more results based off this.

So, I am looking for a proof that **DOES NOT** involve equivalence of norms in any finite-dimensional normed space (because we proved this equivalence based off this). Also, I'm looking for a straight-forward proof - [not using this famous auxiliary lemma that is visible here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170063/proof-of-the-lemma-used-in-proving-that-a-finite-dimensional-normed-space-is-com)

**Question.** Let $X = (X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a finite-dimensional normed space such that $\dim(X)= n \in \Bbb N$. Consider the linear operator $T: (X,\|\cdot\|) \to (\Bbb K^n, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ (here, note that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the usual *supremum* norm in $\Bbb K^n$ and $\Bbb K = \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb K = \Bbb C)$ defined as
$$ T(x) = T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ie_i\right) = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n).$$
where $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is a basis of $X$ and $\alpha_j \in \Bbb K, \, \forall j \in \{1,\dots,n\}.$ Show that $T$ is bounded.

**My attempt.** Proving that $T$ is bounded is simply proving that:
$$ \forall x \in X, \quad \| T(x) \|_\infty \leqslant c\|x\|, \quad \text{for some $c>0$}.$$
Well,
$$\| T(x)\|_\infty = \|(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)  \|_\infty = \max_{1\leqslant i \leqslant n} |\alpha_i| \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i|\left(\frac{\|e_i\|}{\|e_i\|}\right)$$
And from here, we can apply some norm properties,which follow below:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i|\left(\frac{\|e_i\|}{\|e_i\|}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \| \alpha_i e_i \| \frac{1}{\|e_i\|}$$

But I don't know what to do next (?)

If anyone can help with this one I would be really apreciatted.

**NOTE.** If it somehow helps, the inverse operator $T^{-1}$ exists and it is bounded (in fact, it is a well known operator).

Comment: If we write out what it means for $T$ to be bounded, we see that we are trying to show that there exists a $C>0$ such that $C \|\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i e_i\| \ge\sup_n |\alpha_n|$. This is basically the same statement as the lemma. 

You know how to go from the lemma to this inequality. To go the other way, write $\sum_{i = 1}^n |\alpha_i| \le n \sup_k |\alpha_k|$ so that $T$ being bounded immediately yields $\sum_{i = 1}^n |\alpha_i| \le Cn\|\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i e_i\|$. This means that that lemma isn't that strong and it will be hard to prove this statement without basically proving the lemma.

Comment: You wrote "WLOG $\dim(X)=n$". But the way you wrote, there is loss in generality since $n$ is the dimension of the target space $\mathbb K^n$. Writing "WLOG $\dim(X)=m$" would be better.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro That's true! Altough, I believe the result is true **iff** $\dim(X) =n$, I shouldn't have written WLOG at all. Thanks for your comment. I will edit the post.

Comment: I would also avoid using "generic" like that. That operator does not look generic to me. On the contrary, it is very specific. Besides, "generic" has a precise meaning in the context of Baire category and that leads to further confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty much the same than the proof that all norms are equivalent.

Let $L=T^{-1} \colon (\Bbb K^n,\|\cdot\|_{\infty}) \to (X,\|\cdot\|)$.
As you said, $L$ is bounded.
Hence, it is continuous (it is a property of linear maps).

From [Bolzano-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), the unit sphere $S$ of $(\Bbb K^n,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is compact.
Consider
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
f\colon & S & \longrightarrow & \Bbb R\\
&x & \longmapsto & \|L(x)\|
\end{array}.
$$
$f$ is continuous on $S$ compact, so that $c=\min f$ exists and is positive since $L$ is injective.
By homogeneity, we have
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb K^n,\quad c\|x\|_{\infty}\leqslant \|L(x)\|.
$$
Taking $x=L^{-1}(y) = T(y)$ now yields
$$
\forall y \in X,\quad \|T(y)\|_{\infty}\leqslant \frac{1}{c}\|y\|.
$$

Comment: I understand your point, but this is **NOT** what I am looking for. A straightforward proof of boundedness shouldn't involve compactness.

Comment: @Fire I'm really not sure that there exists a more straightforward approach. After all, what you want to show is the existence of a supremum of $\max\{|\alpha_i|\}$ for $\alpha_ie_i$ in the $\|\cdot\|$-unit sphere: this *is* pretty close to a compactness statement. It wouldn't be true in infinite dimension (where spheres aren't compact anymore). Moreover, it only uses an *elementary* compactness statement: the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, telling you that the particular case of the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$-unit sphere is compact.

Comment: @Fire Moreover, you **don't know anything** on $\|\cdot\|$ despite it being a norm. Be sure that you will not find a general procedure to determine an upper bound on the unit sphere: it can be arbitrarily big or small.

Comment: I have to say I really tend to agree with you... I have to talk with the lecturer.  Anyway, after reading your answer I have some doubts: *Why precisely is $c = \min f$ positive?* Also, can you be more explicit why the inequality below holds ? $$ \forall x \in \Bbb K^n, \quad c\|x\|_\infty \leqslant \|L(x)\|.$$

Comment: @Fire $f$ is obviously non-negative, and its minimum cannot be zero: otherwise, $L$ would vanish on a non-zero vector (recall that $L$ is a linear isomorphism). Secondly, for $x$ non-zero, apply $c\leqslant \|L(x/\|x\|_{\infty})\|$, since $\|(x/\|x\|_{\infty})\|_{\infty} = 1$. Multiply on both sides, and notice it is still true for $x=0$.

Comment: Is this *straightforward* approach valid? $$ \|Tx\|_\infty = \max_{1\leqslant i \leqslant n} |\alpha_i| = |x_j| = |x_j|\frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|} = \frac{|x_j|}{\|x\|}\|x\|. $$ Since $\frac{|x_j|}{\|x\|} > 0$, we have just proved that $T$ is bounded, for $x \neq 0_X$. For $x = 0_X$, the inequality comes trivially.

Comment: @Fire How do you show that $\frac{|x_j|}{\|x\|}$ can be bounded independently of $x$? I doubt this is valid as it is. To show that this function is bounded and this will rely on a compactness argument I guess.

Comment: What do you mean by "bounded indendently of $x$"? Are you talking about the cases where $\|x\|$ is arbitrary close to $0$ ? I spoke with my lecturer and he said there should be a direct approach for this which lead me to be (even more) confused.

Comment: @Fire I mean, to show that $T$ is bounded, you need to find $c>0$ such that for all $x$, $\|Tx\|_{\infty} \leqslant c \|x\|$. $c$ is thus independent of $x$. Here, you choose $c= |x_j|/\|x\|$, which depends on $x$. You have shown nothing then.

Comment: @Fire Either your lecturer knows something that I don't, either they can be wrong. Both are plausible.

Comment: What if I do this? Instead of $c = |x_j|/\|x\|$: $$ \|Tx\|_\infty = \frac{|x_j|}{\|x\|}\|x\| \leqslant \frac{|x_j|}{\min_{x\neq 0_X}\|x\|}\|x\|.$$ Like this, it is valid for every element $x \in X$, no?

Comment: @Fire There is no $\min_{x \neq 0}\|x\|$, and $\inf_{x\neq 0} \|x\| = 0$. Even though it were defined (which isn't) you still have $|x_j|$ on the top, which depends on $x$...Think about that: you are trying to find an upper bound of $\frac{\sup_j |x_j|}{\|x\|}$ for $x\neq 0$. This is exactly showing that $\frac{\|Tx\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|}$ is bounded above, or equivalently, that $\frac{\|x\|}{\|Tx\|_{\infty}}$ is bounded below by a positive constant... Which is what I did in my answer.

Comment: I was going through your answer again and it looks really perfect to me: I only have one question: why exactly do we need to use the claim $S$ is compact? The fact that $S$ is closed and bounded isn't enough to guarantee there exists a minimum of $f$ on $S$ ? (From Weierstrass theorem)

Comment: Moreover, what is the theorem behind $f$ continuous on$S$ compact $\Rightarrow$ $f$ has a minimum on $S$?

Comment: @Fire The Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem says that in $(\Bbb K^n, \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ (where $\Bbb K = \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ of course), closed and bounded is equivalent to compact. The other result is: If $f\colon X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, then $f$ has a global minimum / maximum. It is a really classic, and sometimes called the [Extreme value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem). Note that it again relies on the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, applied to $(\Bbb R, |\cdot |)$ (that is the case $n=1$).

Comment: The *extreme value theorem* you linked  (applied to this exercise) claims that if $f$ is continuous on $S$ (which is closed - this is provable) then $f$ attains a minimum on $S$. I don't see where compactness is needed here (?) As a matter fact, we can say $S$ is compact since it is closed and bounded (from, as you said, *Bolzano-Weierstrass*).

Comment: @Fire See the generalization section, below in the wiki article. Closed is not enough: closed and bounded in $\Bbb R$ (which is equivalent to compact) is the right assumption. In general, the right assumption is compact. Counter-example for only closed: the identity map $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, since $\Bbb R$ is closed...

Comment: Thanks! I got it!